# Import CSV with comma in a field with load data infile

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I have a CSV file with format as below

```
nconst,primaryName,birthYear,deathYear,primaryProfession,knownForTitles
nm0000001,Fred,1899,1987,"soundtrack,actor,miscellaneous","tt0072308,tt0045537"
nm0000002,Lauren,1924,2014,"actress,soundtrack","tt0038355,tt0117057,tt0037382"
```

Some fields are enclosed in quotes `("")` which is not an issue and also fields have a comma `(,)` as a delimiter.

I am using below command in mysql command line:

```
load data local infile '/home/ec2-user/sample.csv' into table movies.`sample` fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines;
```

which intern gives no error but data is inserted in the table in below wrong format:

```
**nm0000001**   Fred  1899  1987    soundtrack,actor,miscellaneous  tt0043044,tt0072308,tt0050419,tt0045537" **nm0000002**,Lauren Bacall,1924,2014,"actress,soundtrack
```

As we can clearly see , **data from 2nd row appends in the first row**

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** :

table definition :

```
 CREATE TABLE `sample` (
   `nconst` text,
   `primaryName` text,
   `birthYear` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `deathYear` text,
   `primaryProfession` text,
   `knownForTitles` text
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please add table definition.

Comment: How did you get fred astaire uploaded when only fred appears in the csv file?

Comment: it was Fred Astaire only , i changed for sake of formatting

Comment: I'd confirm that you definitely have a \n as a line delimiter and not just a \r - also, I'd use OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'

Comment: did the optionally thing , no effect

Comment: Try \r rather than \n

Comment: it WORKED.. but how ???

Comment: Because your line terminator *Isnt* a \n, its a \r in this case - as I pointed out in my comment above.

Comment: but i cant see it , how did you deduce that ?

Comment: @amol, because line feeds used to be CR/LF (old typewriter stuff, carriage return, line feed .. move the print head back to the start (carriage return) and move to the next line (line feed)).  CR is \r and lf is \n (new line).  The line terminator is one of those, or the combination of both, so if 1 doesn't work, its usually the other.